# Module within imported package is not visible until explicitly imported

Tags: python, package, python-import

I have a problem I have come across a few times with various packages. I import the package as a whole and try to access a module, but it is apparently not there. However once I explicitly import it separately, it's available back in my original imported namespace. What's happening here?

Example below:

```
import email
print(email.policy)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'policy'

from email import policy
print(email.policy)
<module 'email.policy' from 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\email\\policy.py'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sourced from [my wikipage](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/wiki/ImportSideEffects) which I've written in the past about this:

### Import Side-effects

Importing a package does not mean that the sub-packages/sub-modules are imported (though sometimes it may look like that!)

Consider the following:

```
$ tree
.
└── pkg
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── mod2.py
    └── mod.py

1 directory, 3 files


$ tail -n 999 pkg/*
==> pkg/__init__.py <==

==> pkg/mod2.py <==
import pkg.mod
x = 2

==> pkg/mod.py <==
hi = 1


>>> import pkg
# Doesn't work!
>>> pkg.mod
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mod'
# But if we import some module that has a side-effect of importing that module
>>> import pkg.mod2
# Suddenly it works!
# DON'T EVER DEPEND ON THIS BEHAVIOUR!
>>> pkg.mod
<module 'pkg.mod' from 'pkg/mod.py'>
```

In short, *sometimes* it may appear that importing a package imports its subpackages, but only if the `__init__.py` of that package imports it.  Generally, don't depend on this behaviour and be explicit about importing sub-packages.